# Unexpected end of file - php

Tags: php

```
<?php session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'])
{
    header('Location: /admin');
}

include 'includes/header.inc'; ?>

<div class="main_content_wrapper">

    <div class="main_content limit_main_content_width margin_center p20">

        <div class="question_wrapper main_content_content homepage_section" style='margin-top: 20px'>
            <div>Ask any cooking related doubts or learn from already answered quesetions.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="question_wrapper main_content_content homepage_section">

            <div class='big_heading'>Ask your doubt</div>
            <div class="question_wrapper_content question_div_wrapper mb10">
                <div class="question_wrapper_content question_div_wrapper placeholder_text js_main_question_placeholder">Write your question here</div>
                <div class='question_wrapper_content question_div_wrapper ask_question_box p20 subtle_border radius3 mb10 js_main_question_value js_main_question_input' contenteditable='true'></div>
                <input type="email" class="p20 subtle_border question_wrapper_content email_input js_main_email_value" placeholder='Enter your email here'>
                <div class="g-recaptcha mt10" data-sitekey="6LcIo9oSAAAAAPTdolZGu6RoMDybW0Q66-TLTkbV"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="everyOtherGreenButton inline_middle question_wrapper_content submit_main_question js_submit_main_question center_align">ASK ME NOW</div>
            <div class="everyOtherGreenButton inline_middle question_wrapper_content sending_main_question js_sending_main_question center_align noafter">SENDING...</div>
            <div class='inline_middle bold question_wrapper_content response_message question_sent_success js_question_sent_success'>Success! You will receive an email when Kavita answers the question. :D</div>
            <div class='inline_middle bold question_wrapper_content response_message question_sent_error js_question_sent_error'>There was an unknown error :( Please try again or refresh the page.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="question_wrapper main_content_content homepage_section">

        <div class='big_heading'>Recently answered questions</div>
        <div class="recently_answered_wrapper">

            <?php

            include 'includes/database_login.inc';

            $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published = 1 and deleted = 0 and answered = 1 ORDER BY answered_on DESC LIMIT 5";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
            echo $result->num_rows;
            $rowCount = '2';
            echo $rowCount;
            $p_index = 0;

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

                ?><a href='/post.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>' class="recently_answered_wrapper_content recently_answered_question inline_middle subtle_border recent<?php echo $p_index%4; ?>">

                <div class="title p10 bold">Q. <?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>
                <div class="answer p10" style='padding-top: 0'><?php echo $row['answer']; ?></div>

                </a><?php //$p_index++; 

            }

            $conn->close(); ?><a href='/posts.php' class="recently_answered_wrapper_content recently_answered_question noborder view_all_answered_questions inline_middle center_align">

                <div class="p10 bold" style="margin-top: 55px;">VIEW ALL ANSWERS</div>

            </a>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is a snippet of my php code. I have somehow figured that the error `Unexpected end of file` is happening here. **But I don't see why.**

**UPDATE**
When I comment out `echo $rowCount`, it doesnt show any errors.

Comment: The error isn't happening there. It's happening somewhere you have an unclosed bracket (`{`) or possibly parenthesis (`(`). You would need to post more code for us to identify the exact problem.

Comment: Perhaps the block you posted is in an `if` or `else` block or a loop without the closing `}`?

Comment: Added code for you to see

Comment: I even tried verifying the php code at http://www.phpcodechecker.com. It said it has no issues.

Comment: Please post footer.inc, as well.

Comment: I'l just remove the footer include .. the error still occurs after removing.

Comment: What if you remove all the other includes?